# Streaming from Glass to Android phone

Tags: google-glass

I would like to be able to get the streaming images from Glass to the Android device that pears with the Glass, like MyGlass Screencast but with the ability to get the streaming as byte[] to my Android application, after I would like to capture an image with the Glass and send it to my Android Application for image manipulation.
is all possible with the current GDK version, any sample code will be helpful.

Thank's,

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you cannot do that with the current API.  Google obviously has access to private functionality that they don't expose to the public.

Here is a related request: http://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=404

Of course, there is always a way to do these things, if you are willing to hack your glass a bit, and work outside of the official Google supplied APIs.

Comment: Thank's what about sending the images from Glass to Android device using basic http connection or Bluetooth?